# using awk to find if a column contains "|"

Tags: awk

This is the command I'm trying to run

```
awk '/$4 ~ \|/' text.txt
```

This is what is in text.txt

```
27  34  83  38|27   93
38  38  02  38  02
```

I want

```
27  34  83  38|27   93
```

As output but I am receiving nothing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You `awk` command:

```
awk '/$4 ~ \|/' text.txt
```

The issue here is that it treats the whole string `$4 ~ \|` as a regular expression.  You probably wanted

```
 awk '$4 ~ /\|/' text.txt
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to match `$4` with a regular expression literal, not put it inside the reg ex.

Try

```
awk '$4 ~ /\|/' text.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

You can split the record using pipe as the delimiter, then output only records where there are more than 1 field:

```
awk -F"|" 'NF>1' yourfile.txt
```

Comment: The OP wants to output the record when field 4 contains a `|`, not when it appears anywhere in the record.